# in which situation the comparison of objects methods in java script returns false

Tags: javascript

A few days ago i seen an example compare instances of objects with their methods that returns true or false, and i try to do this by my self.As explained to me, if i declare method inside Object , not in his prototype, it must return false in this example, but i'm getting true :

```
function Foo(name, lastName) {
    this.name = name,
    this.lastName = lastName,
    this.show = function() {
       return this.name;
    }
}

function Foo2(name, lastName) {
    Foo.apply(this, arguments);
}

Foo2.prototype = Foo.prototype;
Foo2.prototype.constructor = Foo2;

var x = new Foo2("Peter", "Pan");
var y = new Foo2("John", "English");

console.log(x.show() === y.show());// true, why not false? it is two differed functions
```

When i comparing them, the result is true, but i can't understand why?
If i declaring property inside the object and doing new Object, i created two different functions, and when i declaring in prototype, it's creating one function that equal.

thank's for any advice.

Comment: You're not comparing the functions, you're comparing what the functions return.

Comment: and with what function i can compare them?

Comment: Putting `()` after a function calls the function. Use the name without `()`: `console.log(x.show === y.show))`.

Comment: BTW, I tried your example and it returned `false`. `x.show()` returns `"Peter"`, `y.show()` returns `"John"`, and they're not equal.

Comment: Change it to `y = new Foo2("Peter", "English")`, then your example returns `true`, but comparing the functions returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the functions and comparing their return values, not the functions themselves. To refer to the functions themselves, use the name without `()` after it.

```
var x = new Foo2("Peter", "Pan");
var y = new Foo2("Peter", "English");

console.log(x.show() === y.show()); // true
console.log(x.show === y.show); // false
```

Comment: @HMR There's no John in my example. I changed that from the example in the question because it was returning `false` when he claimed it returned `true`. The `show` functions are not the same because it's not in the prototype, it's a closure that gets created newly in the constructor.